# Pandas format datetime with many different date types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to format the column 'Data' to make a pattern with dates.

The formats I have are:

```
1/30/20 16:00
1/31/2020 23:59
2020-02-02T23:43:02
```

Here is the code for the dataframe.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
url = "https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports"
csv_only  = [i.split("=")[1][1:-1] for i in requests.get(url).text.split(" ") if '.csv' in i and 'title' in i]

combo = [pd.read_csv(url.replace("github","raw.githubusercontent").replace("/tree/","/")+"/"+f) for f in csv_only]

one_df = pd.concat(combo,ignore_index=True)

one_df["País"] = one_df["Country/Region"].fillna(one_df["Country_Region"])
one_df["Data"] = one_df["Last Update"].fillna(one_df["Last_Update"])
```

I tried adding the code bellow but it doesn't bring the result I wanted

```
pd.to_datetime(one_df['Data'])
one_df.style.format({"Data": lambda t: t.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")})
```

Any help?

**UPDATE**

This is the complete code, but it doesn't work. Many exceptions printed with different date formats.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
url = "https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports"
csv_only  = [i.split("=")[1][1:-1] for i in requests.get(url).text.split(" ") if '.csv' in i and 'title' in i]

combo = [pd.read_csv(url.replace("github","raw.githubusercontent").replace("/tree/","/")+"/"+f) for f in csv_only]

one_df = pd.concat(combo,ignore_index=True)

df = pd.DataFrame()
DATE_FORMATS = ["%m/%d/%y %H:%M", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", "%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S"]

df["Região"] = one_df["Province/State"].fillna(one_df["Admin2"])
df["País"] = one_df["Country/Region"].fillna(one_df["Country_Region"])
df["Data"] = one_df["Last Update"].fillna(one_df["Last_Update"])
df["Confirmados"] = one_df["Confirmed"]
df["Mortes"] = one_df["Deaths"]
df["Recuperados"] = one_df["Recovered"]

def parse(x_):
    for fmt in DATE_FORMATS :
        try:
            tmp = datetime.strptime(x_, fmt).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
            return tmp
        except ValueError:
            print(x_)

pd.to_datetime(df['Data'])
df['Data'] = df['Data'].apply(lambda x: parse(x))

#df['Data'].strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
#df['Data'] = df['Data'].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') if x else '')

df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\guilh\Downloads\Covid2\Covid-19.xlsx', index=False,  encoding="utf8")
print(df)
```

Comment: Assuming the date column is the same format within a csv, you could try to convert it before concat all the file together?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(one_df['Data'])` works for me.

Comment: When i try to format for `%d/%m/%Y`, i get `ValueError: time data '1/22/2020 17:00' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y' (match)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
```

You could save all possible formats in a list as -

```
DATE_FORMATS = ["%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", "%m/%d/%y %H:%M", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"]
```

Define a function that loops through the formats and tries to parse it.
(Fixed a bug, where the `print` statement should have been outside the `for` loop)

```
issues = set()
def parse(x_):
    for fmt in DATE_FORMATS:
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(x_, fmt).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
        except ValueError:
            pass
    issues.add(x_)


sample = ["1/30/20 16:00", "1/31/2020 23:59", "2020-02-02T23:43:02"]

df = pd.DataFrame({'data': sample})
df['data'] = df['data'].apply(lambda x: parse(x))

assert df['Data'].isna().sum() == len(issues) == 0, "Issues observed, nulls observed in dataframe"

print("Done")
```

Output

```
         data
0  01/30/2020
1  01/31/2020
2  02/02/2020
```

If `df.apply()` comes across a particular date format that hasn't been defined in the list, it would simply print `None` since nothing would be returned by the function `parse()`

Comment: How could I add a line to print the exception dates so I can map them in DATE_FORMATS? I can't get None on the dates since the data analysis depends on precise dates and countries

Comment: within the `except` clause you can add a `print(x_)` (remove the `pass`), this will print the date with the unrecognized format.

Comment: I got many exceptions, with `2020-02-24T14:43:03`, `2020-02-24 14:43:03` and other date formats. I updated the question with my complete code including this answer of yours, am i using it wrong?

Comment: @guialmachado So, basically there was a flaw in my code, all the dates were being parsed but were needlessly printed out due to the incorrect position of the statement `print(x_)`, kindly check my edited code now.

Answer (score 0):

also here, letting [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) infer the format does the trick:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.to_datetime(["1/30/20 16:00", "1/31/2020 23:59", "2020-02-02T23:43:02"])

print(s)
# DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-30 16:00:00', '2020-01-31 23:59:00',
#                '2020-02-02 23:43:02'],
#               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Note that if your date/time format generally provides the day first (e.g. `30.1.2021` for Jan 30th 2021), set keyword `dayfirst=True`.