# Dealing with "+00:00" in datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, datetime

How do you convert a column of dates of the form "2020-06-30 15:20:13.078196+00:00" to datetime in pandas?

This is what I have done:

1. `pd.concat([df, df.date_string.apply(lambda s: pd.Series({'date':datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')}))], axis=1)`
2. `pd.concat([df, df.file_created.apply(lambda s: pd.Series({'date':datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f.%z')}))], axis=1)`
3. `pd.concat([df, df.file_created.apply(lambda s: pd.Series({'date':datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f:%z')}))], axis=1)`

I get the error - `time data '2020-06-30 15:20:13.078196+00:00' does not match format` in all cases.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your format is looking for a literal character `T` that separates the date from time. You should either replace that with a space, or your input data isn't consistent with using `T`.

Comment: I removed the T, still getting the same error - `time data '2020-06-30 15:20:13.078196+00:00' does not match format`

Comment: Did you remove the T, or replace it with a space?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`+00:00` is a UTC offset of zero hours, thus can be interpreted as UTC. The easiest thing to do is let [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) auto-infer the format. That works very well for standard formats like this ([ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)):

```
import pandas as pd

dti = pd.to_datetime(["2020-06-30 15:20:13.078196+00:00"])

print(dti)
# DatetimeIndex(['2020-06-30 15:20:13.078196+00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', freq=None)
```

Notes

- pandas v2 allows you to set `format="ISO8601"` to specify that your input is in that format. It even allows parsing a mix of ISO8601 compatible strings: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78040502/10197418).
- `pd.to_datetime` also works very well for mixed formats: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69513960/10197418). In pandas v2, you can set `format="mixed"` in such cases.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works. For others who come searching - this is what I did:
`df['date'] = pd.to_dataframe(df.string_date, infer_datetime_format = True)`

Comment: @Nilima glad I could help; setting `infer_datetime_format=True` can give some better performance if the date/time strings in the column you're converting only have one format (all strings formatted the same way).

Answer (score 4):

None of the formats mentioned by you above matches your sample.
Try this

> "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z" (Notice the space before %H).