# Converting to datetime, assuming a part of the date can miss

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Let's say I have a simple two row df:

```
|     date_column      |
|----------------------|
|10/23/2001 12:34:44 AM|
|10/23/2001 12:33:44   |
|----------------------|
```

If I run the line:

```
df[date_column] = pd.to_datetime(df[date_colummn], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

I get the error

> 'unconverted data remains'

but I am perfectly okay with the `'%p'` missing, I just want to get the `%m/%d/%Y`.

Is there any way to achieve this? Can I tell pandas to parse only the present data in my "format" and ignore the rest, if it's missing?

**UDPATE**

looks like this keyword, according to the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) might do the trick:

```
exact: bool, True by default
Behaves as: - If True, require an exact format match. - If False, allow the format to match anywhere in the target string.
```

Comment: I've provided a solution here to tackle multiple datetime formats - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61418389/pandas-format-datetime-with-many-different-date-types/61423853#61423853 Have a look..

Comment: @tidakdiinginkan Thanks for your very elaborated answer, but I am looking in a way to do it with a one liner in pandas, I have been reading the docs  like crazy  I think the keyword "exact" will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply let `pandas` [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) infer the format:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.to_datetime(["10/23/2001 12:34:44 AM", "10/23/2001 12:33:44"])

print(s)
# DatetimeIndex(['2001-10-23 00:34:44', '2001-10-23 12:33:44'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Note that if AM/PM is not specified, 24h clock is assumed. Also, the month is assumed to come first (the day second).